# My device has 720px resolution but in browser width is 360px

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, mobile-website

My mobile device is HTC One X, resolution: **720x1280**

I need to do responsive web-page

in html i write `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />`

But in browser i have 360px width. I have checked it using `$(window).width()` or  `document.width`

Comment: Use `document.width*(window.devicePixelRatio||1)` to get actual width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It renders at 360px wide, but the depth is 720px.  In other words, it uses 4 pixels to display 1 normal pixel.  So all normal graphics will appear blurry as it's upscaling the image twice the size.  So the solution would be to create twice as big images, and scale them down 50%.

Comment: Checkout:
[How to get real Mobile CSS resolutions for Responsive Design](https://coderwall.com/p/ygcyha/how-to-get-real-mobile-css-resolutions-for-responsive-design)

It is more accurate, even though the link to the Wikipedia there is not working.

Check [Pixel Aspect Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio) too

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, the syntax when declaring the viewpoint should be:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

Note that it uses commas instead of semi-colons, and there isn't any anything directly before the closing />.

From what I've read, using semi-colons may cause issues with certain browsers.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That may be your compressed resolution, not your scaled resolution.

If you look at the specs for your smartphone, you will see that a 4.7inch screen has 1280px by 720px resolution. [See specs.](http://smartphones.techcrunch.com/q/249/4793/What-are-the-specifications-of-the-HTC-One-X-smartphone) That is approximately the same resolution as my 13" Macbook, which is impossible since my Macbook is over twice as wide. Hence, they are marketing the compressed resolution, which is not the resolution that browsers consider in handling media queries.